# mvc5 autocomplete with accessability to ARIA rules

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, asp.net-mvc-5, accessibility, wai-aria

I have code for autocomplete that is based on jQuery autocomplete. I want to change the code so that it conforms to the accessibility rules. I'm having difficulties finding accessible autocomplete library. My non-accessible code was taken from  Implement jQuery AutoComplete TextBox in ASP.Net MVC on ASPSnippets.com.

I would appreciate help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might consider Nicolas Hoffmann's [jQuery accessible autocomplete list](https://github.com/nico3333fr/jquery-accessible-autocomplete-list-aria) (under MIT licence on GitHub). See the test page [jQuery accessible autocomplete list (with some ARIA)](https://a11y.nicolas-hoffmann.net/autocomplete-list/).

The [Autocomplete](http://www.bu.edu/webteam/clrux/accessibility/autocomplete/autocomplete.html) example hosted at Boston University claims to be accessible; it uses only jQuery and jQuery UI, and the test page does not mention recent browsers (it mentions tests with Internet Explorer up to version 9, Firefox 17, Chrome 24).

Comment: Thank! can I use this plugin for multiple values?

Comment: @LiorKonimbo I'm afraid I don't know; I have not tested it on a site of my own.